# How to conditionally check an object with phpspec?

Tags: php, laravel, tdd, phpspec

I just started learning phpspec and I have a question.
Ok, you can check if a value is equal to some other value, and if you want to see if a value is between some values you can create a matcher like this:

```
function getMatchers()
{
    return [            
        'beBetween' => function ($subject, $min, $max) {
                if ($subject >= $min && $subject <= $max) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }           
    ];
}
```

and make a test like

```
$this->some_method()->getValue()->shouldBeBetween(1,6);
```

but how can you do a conditional? 
Let's say that the value that`some_method()` returns is 1
how can we say to phpspec to look at another property of the object beeing tested?

I'm making a simple dice class. And I want for each die roll to return and array with the the value of the roll and a status. If the die roll is the minimum the status should be "critical_miss" and if the roll is the maximum, the status should be "critical_hit".

So, I want to test this...

roll the die.
the die roll value should be between 1 and 6
if the die roll value is 1, the die roll status should be 'critical_miss'
if the die roll value is 6, the die roll status should be 'critical_hit'

Can you do such a test in phpspec?

Thank you

Comment: Then you write more than one test! The way I see it a test is something like:

"You send your class A value X. You make sure you get Y in return. Optionally having use Z method in B class". 
If you have some conditions you write a test for every scenario.
Given you example includes randomness, I'd extract the "random number generating" into another class so that you can mock it in order to test separately your "status logic".